# Can't open Solution - Because of my Visual Studio version?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a project where they asked me to use Visual Studio 2013 so I downloaded but I'm still having problem opening up the solution. This is the error message:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - {name}.OutlookAddIn, "{path}\{name}.OutlookAddIn.csproj"
     - {name}.Installer, "{path}\{name}.Installer.vdproj"


No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - {name}, "{path}\{name}.csproj"
     - {name}, "{path}\{my_solution}.sln"
```

The error message in the Migration Report:

```
{name}.Installer\{name}.Installer.vdproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C

{name}.OutlookAddIn\{name}.OutlookAddIn.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33
```

When I open up the Solution file in a text editor I can see that they used an older Visual Studio version than mine:

```
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

My version:

```
12.0.40629.00 Update 5
```

I also tried to open the Solution in Visual Studio 2015 with the same problem.

Is it possible to download the specific version (`12.0.21005.1`) to see if I would be able to open the solution without problems?

Or is it possible, from the information from Visual Studio and the Migration Report, to know what to do?

Or is it possible that the Community version that I'm using is causing these problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup projects are no longer supported by newer versions of VS. E.g.:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs/

As for OutlookAddIn project, I guess you need some additional plugin to VS?

Comment: Thanks Sir! Together with the link that you provided and Web Developer Tools (which apparently includes Office Developer Tools) made it work.

Comment: From the article, a VS extension is available to address this gap.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects